# Decimal value on d3.js y axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

[image]

I am having an issue with adjusting scale on y-axis for a d3.js visualization that I am working on.
On the scale, it is showing the values as 1.0,2.0
1[Y-axis for d3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw4gX.png)

I want to change the value to 0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6 instead 3,4,5,6.

My code is attached below :

```
  var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(stateById.values(), function(d) { return d.total; })])
  .rangeRound([height, 0])
  .nice();
```

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .tickFormat(d3.format(".1f"));

please advise on what change I should make in the line above. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Essentially what you need to do is change the `tickFormat` function to divide the datum by ten. It may also be good practice to store the `d3.format(".1f")` in an external variable and use that instead.

```
.tickFormat(function (d){
    return d3.format(".1f")(d/10);
})
```

Comment: Hello JSBob. You are a lifesaver! Thank you so much.

Comment: How to convert dot to comma. 

I get the array value for example 1.2 and I need to show 1,2 on the linechart

Comment: you can also check out this http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/05c1e95bf7aa16c4768e for detailed formats